# Test the smart on FHIR application on any production ready EHR. Avoid second level of authentication after launch inside EHR

Tags: epic, smart-on-fhir

I have a SOF application built for EHR systems like Cerner, EPIC, Athena etc. The application runs well on sandbox environments. However, when I tried to check if the app is ready, before going for non-production and production environment, using open EMR. I encountered a strange issue where the application authenticates twice in open EMR, once before launch (EHR login) and once during launch (when clicked on launch). I am afraid that the same would happen when deployed to an actual EHR. (Open EMR is considered as the production version of Cerner and EPIC)

Even if I think it's a bug or a feature from openEMR, is there a way to test my app in any production similar environment of EHR (not sandbox)? Please suggest!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get access to a true production environment would be to implement your app with a customer and to install and test the app within their testing and production environments.

Sometimes EHRs offer ways to simulate or test SMART on FHIR apps using their client or a simulation harness. Generally speaking, you need to be a member of their developer/marketplace program in order to do this. Cerner provides some details [here](https://fhir.cerner.com/smart/#code-console). Epic has a testing harness [here](https://open.epic.com/Hyperdrive/Hyperdrive). athenahealth has a mixture of info but [this page](https://docs.athenahealth.com/api/guides/our-process) walks through the process for getting access to a preview sandbox.